# SQL check if non-unique record exists—If it does, UPDATE; if not, INSERT the record INTO the table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

This seems like it would be a common scenario, but I can't seem to find anything on it.

I'm trying to duplicate some records in a WordPress database on the wp_postmeta table, and changing the `meta_key` value on the duplicate.

However, some rows with the `meta_key` value already exist with blank `meta_value` fields. So, when duplicating, I want to check if the record with a given `post_id` and `meta_key` value exists, and if so, UPDATE it; if not, INSERT the record INTO the table.

Since it's the wp_postmeta table, it's possible for lots of records to have non-unique `post_id` and `meta_key` values, so I haven't had luck with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Here's what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT o.post_id, '_new_column_name', o.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta o
WHERE o.meta_key = '_old_column_name'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = o.post_id AND meta_key = o.meta_key
);
```

This query returns 0 results.

I don't simply want to rename the columns, because I want to keep those records with the old column names in the database, just in case.

I'm using MariaDB 10.4

Comment: You mean you cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because I could not add a unique index/constraint on `(post_id, meta_key)` (because my database happened to already have duplicate post_id/meta_key rows), here's what ended up working for me.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, let me know if there's any problems with the solution:

```
REPLACE INTO wp_postmeta (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT 
    IFNULL( 
        (SELECT n.meta_id FROM wp_postmeta n 
         WHERE n.meta_key = '_new_column_name' 
         AND n.post_id = o.post_id ), 
        NULL 
    ), 
    o.post_id, '_new_column_name', o.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta o
WHERE meta_key = '_old_column_name';
```

Comment: `REPLACE` is `DELETE` plus `INSERT`.  So this is probably always worse than IODKU.  And with the uniqueness constraint, you can avoid that subquery.  (Some other fixes would be needed.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT o.post_id, '_new_column_name', o.meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta o
    WHERE o.meta_key = '_old_column_name'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(o.meta_value);
```

For this to work, you need a unique index/constraint on `(post_id, meta_key)`:

```
alter table wp_postmeta add constraint unq_postmeta_post_value
    unique(post_id, meta_key);
```

Comment: While you are at it, implement the tips in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) .  You will get a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF .. ELSE` as follows:

```
If exists (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_old_column_name')
  Update wp_postmeta set meta_key = '_new_column_name'
   Where meta_key = '_old_column_name'
Else
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
  SELECT o.post_id, '_new_column_name', o.meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta o
   WHERE o.meta_key = '_old_column_name'
```